# Why Flask does not traceback when it recognizes bad DB connection?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, flask

Could not find any answer to this, I try to create two separated objects for different configurations to separate development environment from production.
So I came up with this config.py file

```py
class BaseConfig:
    SECRET_KEY = 'MYSECRET'

class DevConfig(BaseConfig):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///market.db'
    DEBUG = True

class ProdConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = False
    pg_user = 'admin'
    pg_password = 'admin'
    pg_db = 'mytable'
    pg_host = 'localhost'
    pg_port = '5432'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"postgresql://{pg_user}:{pg_password}@{pg_host}:{pg_port}/{pg_db}"
```

Now I have this config file, I want to test out and see **failure** by purpose when I create a Flask instance and read from `ProdConfig` object (Note: I still don't have Postgres instance running on localhost), but I expect for a connection failure when I start my app. But why it lets me to even run the application?

Project has one package, so here is `__init__.py` of one of my packages:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from market.config import DevConfig, ProdConfig

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(ProdConfig) # Note this one!

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login_page"
login_manager.login_message_category = "info"
```

And I have a `run.py` outside of the package that imports this package, so:

```py
from market import app
#Checks if the run.py file has executed directly and not imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I would expect Flask to fail immediately when the connection could not be established against the DB.

Comment: I'm going to say it is down to connection on demand. In other words the connection code will not fail until something in the app actually attempts to fetch from the database.

Comment: I agree with @AdrianKlaver. From my understanding of things, when you instantiate an SQLAlchemy object flask checks that you have specified SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI  in the configuration file. It will give you a warning if you havent specified SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS but it will still run. Only when you try to use the db object to add/remove something from the database does that poor database connection come to light. Until then flask app will run happily with no issues related to the database.